# How to authenticate with python in modern oauth2

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

I'm on a project to create python script to automate some process.

I'm not familiar with Microsoft OAUTH2 method.

Can anyone share any insights with me on how I can authenticate to an outlook email server in python?

The is fine as I will be parsing through the folders and look for a specific email.

So far, I'm familiar with basic authentication. It's not something I have much experience with but I'm willing to learn from the experts.

Comment: this is not a python question but more of API question. Use libraries like https://pyoutlook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ rather than trying to reinvent the wheel. You can try out examples in the documentation.

Comment: Okay, thank you, so Microsoft is mainly using API now over this method?

Comment: Microsoft gives rest api endpoints for operations, for which you need API keys and tokens. This library just provides you toolkit with methods and classes. The library itself is not microsoft owned.